# Can I pass List<Model> to a function that takes generic wildcard List<?>

Tags: java, android, generics

I have a list view adapter that is reusable across some activities and renders different layouts based on different group items. Since the list view adapter requires flexibility in the collection structure, I've decided to use generics wildcard for the collection:

```
public ExpandableListAdapter(FragmentActivity context, List<String> group,
        Map<String, List<?>> listCollection) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataCollections = listCollection;
}
```

Here's the problem. I have a function that returns a two-level associative array for the adapter. It returns `Map<String, List<Model>>`. Model is a mapping model.

```
public Map<String, List<Model>> getAll() {
    Map<String, List<Model>> listCollection = new HashMap<String,List<Model>>();
    /***Database Query***/
    List<Model> rowList = new ArrayList<Model>();
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Model sf = new Model();
                sf.title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title");
                sf.group_title = DBMethod.getString(cursor,getColumnIndex("group"));
                rowList.add(sf);
                Model group = (Model)listCollection.get(sf.group_title);
                if(group == null){
                   listCollection.put(sf.group_title,rowList);
                }else{
                   listCollection.get(sf.group_title).add(sf);
                }

            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error while trying to get posts from database");
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return listCollection;
}

public class Model{

  public String title;

  public String value;

  public String group_title;

}
```

I understand that the returned array from `getAll()` (`Map<String, List<Model>>`) doesn't match the wildcard collection required by `ExpandableListAdapter` (`Map<String, List<?>>`). But is it still possible to pass it into the adapter? I'm getting incompatible types error in this code:

```
Map<String, List<Model>> listCollection = getAll();

ExpandableListView expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(
            this, groupList, listenCollection);
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
```

I have tried to modify `getAll()` to return `Map<String, List<? extends Model>>`, but it is still getting incompatible type error.

Comment: Did you try `Map<String, ? extends List<?>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare `listCollection` as a `Map<String, List<?>>`, you are declaring that the value type of the map must be *exactly* `List<?>`. The wildcard there actually doesn't gain you much. To get the type flexibility you want, you need an extra wildcard: `Map<String, ? extends List<?>>`.

Note that with this wildcard you will be able to retrieve lists from the map, but not add lists to it.